# Node cannot connect to MySQL for version 17+

Tags: node.js, mysql-connector

I have written a simple test file for Node to access MySQL on my Ubuntu server. For Node versions 14,15,16 it can connect. For Node versions 17,18,19, it cannot.

I am using MySQL 8.0.31 on Ubuntu 20.04. The test file is called test.js and has the following code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "correctpasswordhere"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});
```

I use nvm to select the Node version I want to test. For example, I run

```
nvm install 16
node test.js
```

Output: Connected!

But when I use:

```
nvm install 17
node test.js
```

Output:

```
if (err) throw err;
           ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1195:16)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/root/gatsby_test/node_test/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/root/gatsby_test/node_test/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/root/gatsby_test/node_test/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/gatsby_test/node_test/test.js:9:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1099:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '::1',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true
}

Node.js v17.9.1
```

I'd like to use the latest version of Node but I need it to connect to MySQL. I've Googled around but have only found people referring to having the wrong login credentials. Anyone know what's going on? Thanks!

Comment: Connection refused means that the connection request did not even get to mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `localhost` as hostname if you want to prevent the client from connecting to MySQL over IPv6 (which is what's happening), use `127.0.0.1` instead.

Alternatively, make MySQL listen on IPv6 too.

Comment: Thanks. I changed localhost to 127.0.0.1 and it can now connect for any Node version. Thanks for your help. I will accept your answer once Stackoverflow allows me to.